# Cleaning a non-uniform address in excel

Tags: data-cleaning

If I have non-uniform data in one column like so

[image: non uniform data]

How could I separate it into it's separate components using a macro? Is this a much more difficult question than it looks? This is just a tiny set. The data maybe hundreds of thousands of rows. They could be really messed up,misspelled, It could have strange characters in there like carriage returns.

Comment: In my experience, what you are asking for is difficult and will require scripting, probably VBA scripting.

Comment: converting it from that into a usable format can be fairly straight forward, it's the spell-check and possibility of words being in the wrong place that I would worry about. you would first want to remove unnecessary characters then find a split delimiter. after that you would need to write some logic to recognize the different parts of the address.

VBA scripting would be a necessary requirement.